# Attempting to make Rochelle salt but obtained paste

Tags: home-experiment, salt

I was attempting to make Rochelle salt by adding sodium carbonate to a mixture of cream of tartar and water, but ended up with a solid paste. I kept the cream of tartar/water mix boiling the whole time, which I guess was a mistake, and used a large pan so that there was only a thin depth of liquid. Things seemed to be going more or less as they should, until it suddenly became a paste.

I am letting it cool, but am wondering what I have obtained. Is it potassium sodium tartrate (without the tetrahydrate that would make it Rochelle salt)? If I re-dissolved what I have obtained in water could Rochelle crystals form upon cooling, or is it useless in that respect?

Comment: Free evaporation of solution  at rel. humidity >30% and <84% should be better.// The sudden paste formation can be fast crystallization of oversaturated solution, like Na2SO4 or Na2S2O3 can do.

Comment: Why do you think this paste is not Rochelle salt, to begin with?

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I've not done any chemistry for 20 years, and am really lacking in the fundamentals. I guess my worry is that the water evaporated before all the carbon was removed in the cream of tartar (which I assume is the point where no further bubbling occurs in when one adds sodium carbonate). I also don't know what happens if one keeps adding sodium carbonate beyond what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rochelle salt (sodium potassium tartrate tetrahydrate) is relatively soluble in water (260 g/L at 0ºC, 660 g/L at 26ºC, and melts at 75ºC) (Ref 1), but cream of tartar (potassium bitartrate) is much less soluble (5.7 g/L at 20ºC, 61 g/L at 100ºC) (Ref 2).

Driving the relatively insoluble salt toward the more soluble product should be easy because the sodium carbonate will neutralize the acidity of the tartrate and conversion will be complete. Carbon dioxide will be eliminated even at room temperature, especially with stirring. The boiling and large pan are probably not optimal.

Weighing to very precise proportions would be helpful, but if that is not possible, I suggest you do the best you can to get about 400 g/L of product, starting at room temperature or a *little* higher - way below 75º. Dissolve some sodium carbonate (53 grams would be half a mole, if you use anhydrous; or use 84g (a mole) of $NaHCO_3$) in about 0.72 L water and add 188g cream of tartar, slowly, stirring to insure reaction and dissolution of the potassium bitartrate. You'll wind up with a mole of Rochelle Salt (282g) in  about 650 mL $H_2O$. This is well below the solubility limit. You can filter thru a coffee filter if you like. Then cool in the refrigerator; if you get no crystals, you can cool more in an ice bath and should get some, or, as a last resort, use the freezer.

However, I suspect you can resuscitate your original experiment more easily: add the minimum amount of warm water (with vigorous stirring) to dissolve your paste completely and either allow it to evaporate slowly or cool it in the refrigerator. I'm sure you will get crystals.

Ref 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_sodium_tartrate

Ref 2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_bitartrate